# How to select text inside an <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, css

```
<a href="http://example.com">
   <p>select this text</p>
   <img src="" alt="">
</a>
```

Need to be able to copy text from p tag. The problem that p and img inside a and I can't select it.

I need exactly this HTML structure, as user should be able to copy link from that block. How can I do that?

Comment: `textContent` will give you all of the text within the containing element.

Comment: It is not very clear what exactly you want. Create selection range with JS? Or to allow user selecting content of paragraph with mouse drag? If latter, tell them to hold the ALT key during the selection…

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking for a solution in pure javascript, I'm guessing that this can work ?

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='http://example.com']");
console.log(els[0].textContent);
```

Could be simpler using jQuery

Comment: Way simpler indeed: `jQuery('a p').text()`

Comment: Yes. And to get only that specific link `jQuery('a[href="http://example.com"] p').text()`

Comment: Way simpler is not by targeting `('a p')` (since multiple results). Also way simpler is by using the `$` alias...

Comment: way way simpler would be to set an id on the p and grab its text directly

Answer (score 1):

> This is'nt correct use `block-level` elements as children of `inline` elements.

in your case,use of jQuery like this:

```
var copyStr = $('a[href="http://example.com"] > p').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`textcontent`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp) property

```js
const a = document.querySelector('a');
console.log(a.textContent);
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">
   <p>...</p>
   <img src="" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using Javascript `execCommand("copy")` see this explained in comment:

```js
function CopyText() {
  /* Select Text inside p tag using createTextRange() */
  if (document.selection) { // IE
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.querySelector('#copytext p'));
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.querySelector('#copytext p'));
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  }

  /* Copie the Text inside the input to Clipboard */
  document.execCommand("copy");
  /* Alert success */
  alert("Url Copied to Clipboard")
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%
}http://example.com
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="copytext" onclick="CopyText()">
  <p>http://example.com</p>
  <img src="https://i0.wp.com/wptavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/stack-overflow.png?ssl=1" />
  <input type="text" id="copy" style="opacity:0;height:0;width:0" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply define an id to p tag and pull the text inside p tag using id like following:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var par = $('#pid').text();
  console.log(par)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://example.com">
   <p id="pid">...</p>
   <img src="" />
</a>
```